# How to convert Date in Decimal?

Tags: vb.net

How to convert DateTime in Decimal?

this is my code is not working

```
    Dim c = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 9, 16, 0, 0)

    Dim d As Integer = (c.ToString("%h"))
    Dim duration As Decimal = 0



    Dim date1 As DateTime
    Dim date2 As DateTime

                   If read1("clog") Is (DBNull.Value) Then

                    Else

                        date1 = CDate(read1("clog")).ToString("%h")
                        date2 = CDate(read1("cDlog")).ToString("%h")



                     Dim duration As Decimal = CDec(date2) - CDec(date1)
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: your code is trying to convert Decimal to DateTime, what do you want? Please be more specific.

Comment: i have a two date i need to subtract the two Date.

Comment: You can use `date2 - date1`, which will give a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i will use the timespan its not accurate to calculate...

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit your question and clarify what you *really* want to achieve.

Comment: @Hackweiser What is `read1()`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton read1 is to read my date1

Comment: @Hackweiser Am I correct in thinking that you want to find the difference in hours between `clog` and `cDlog`, regardless of the date? (Incidentally, a Timespan has a resolution of 100 nanoseconds, which I expect is sufficient for your program.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton i  need this output for example (Time In - 9:15:56 AM  - Time Out 07:07:19PM (i need to get the whole hours of this. if 09:16 AM is automatic 1 hour deduction... Thanks in Advanced...

Comment: @Hackweiser Are the dates/times stored in the database with a type of DateTime (good) or as strings (very bad)?

Comment: @Andrew Morton Data type is DateTime...

Comment: @Hackweiser That is good. Your `read1` function should be returning a DateTime, so then you just need to do `date1 = read1("clog") : date2 = read1("cDlog") : Dim duration As Double = (date2 - date1).Hours`; if you want the fractional part of the hours too, use `.TotalHours` instead of `.Hours`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton its not accurate for the total hours  the answer in my output is 9 only (Time In - 9:15:56 AM - Time Out 07:07:19PM) i need the answer 9.5 thank you

Comment: @AndrewMorton Dim date1 As DateTime
                        Dim date2 As DateTime

                        If read1("clog") Is (DBNull.Value) Then

                        Else

                            date1 = read1("clog")
                            date2 = read1("cDlog")


                            Dim duration As Double = (date2 - date1).TotalHours

                            Label9.Text = duration

                        End If

Answer (score 1):

DateTime has the method `Subtract` which you could use.

```
Dim duration As System.TimeSpan
duration = date2.Subtract(date1)
```

Comment: Yes i will use this: my error is Conversion from string "9" to type Date is not valid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Dim duration As TimeSpan
   duration = date1 - date2